# Python access to API- Authentication Error

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I've have been accessing an supportpal API via curl just fine using the following command. (https://docs.supportpal.com/current/REST+API)

```
curl.exe -i -u 'APIKEY:x' -X GET https://support.url.org/api/user/user/3697
```

This correctly grabs the data. I've trying replicate this with python but i continually have issues with authentication and get the following error.

```
Failed to authenticate because of bad credentials or an invalid authorization header
```

The code i'm using is straight forward.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://support.url.org/api/user/user/3697"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer: {APIKEY:x}"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
print(response. Text)
```

I'm thinking i have an issue with the auth header, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests

url = 'https://support.url.org/api/user/user/3697'
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('apikey', x)

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=auth)
```

Comment: is that still passing the API key as a token?

Comment: as it doesn't work and i get a 401 error

Comment: can you check your apikey is proper

Comment: It is the same API key i use with Curl and works.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Nathan can you only pass key like HTTPBasicAuth(x) not 'apikey'  string